# Transfer favorites from Firefox to iPhone's safari

Tags: firefox, iphone

I use Firefox 3.6 on Mac OSX. What is the easiest way of transfer my favorites to iPhone ?

I know I could do; Firefox to Safari, and Safari to iPhone, but this is a bit tedious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, normally, iPhone couldn't sync with FFox directly. I think so.

First, organize your bookmarks, `Bookmarks` >> `Organize Bookmarks` . Choose all bookmarks to export.  Click on the Favorites button on the Bookmarks Library window toolbar and choose Export HTML…. A standard Save dialog box is displayed.

Choose a location and a file name for the exported Bookmarks file and click the Save button. The bookmarks file is saved.

Then, we've to import that saved bookmarks from Safari again. Choose `File` >> `Import Bookmarks` Select the file you exported from Firefox and click the Import  button. The Safari Bookmarks window opens and an item labelled Imported [date] is added at the end of the Bookmarks list in the Collections column. That item contains the Bookmarks you exported from Firefox.

plug your iPhone or iPod touch to iTunes.

Open iTunes.
Select your iPhone or iPod in the Devices portion on the left-hand side of the iTunes window. The right-hand side of the iTunes window displays Settings tabs for the selected device.
Select the Info tab.
Scroll down to the Web Browser section of the Info tab.
Check the box beside Sync Safari bookmarks.

Now when you sync your iPod touch or iPhone to your Mac the Safari bookmarks will be transferred.

Comment: This should work well. It's a bit of a kludge, and won't stay synced, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use a web bookmarking service (like [Delicious](http://del.icio.us) and use your bookmarks on any browser at any time. Not actually answering your question, but a suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com) to automatically keep Firefox and Safari bookmarks in sync, and then sync Safari bookmarks with iPhone bookmarks whenever you do a normal iPhone sync.

This will allow you to keep bookmarks on the iPhone and in Firefox (and Safari too!) in sync without having to perform any manual steps each time.